# Кастомизация на Django

Tags: html, python, css, python-3.x, django

Как сделать так чтобы пользователь мог сам выбрать изображение для фона сайта. 
Сайт на Django2.2

Comment: Позволить ему загрузить файл через форму, сохранить его через модель и потом вытащить из модели ссылку на файл для использования в нужном шаблоне. Все эти темы описаны в документации Django

Comment: @andreymal а если я хочу предоставить выбор из нескольких изображений, и как сохранять через модель, можно пример кода для всего алгоритма?